# How to show cart with number of items in Ubercart?

Tags: views, ubercart

For his cart, my client wants a cart icon with the number of items in it. Not a list of all items. I searched around a little bit but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ubercart core 'shopping cart' block doesn't work for what you need:

[image]

Then you'll need to output it in your theme or create it as your own custom block.
Use the [uc_cart_get_contents() function](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_cart_get_contents). This loads an array of all the items in their cart, which allows you to get a quick [count()](http://php.net/count) on to get your number. From there it is trivial to overlay this output on to your cart icon.

```
// Load the current shopping cart.
$items = uc_cart_get_contents();

// Display a message if the cart has more than 5 products.
$item_count = count($items);

print "<span class='count'>$item_count</span><img src='your_cart_icon.gif'>";
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing... If i want the block to display only if there's one or more items in it?

Comment: use count() again but wrap it in an if statement, ex. if (count($items)) then print the cart, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: sorry i'm not very good with php. I did the following but it didn't work:

<?php 
// Load the current shopping cart.
$items = uc_cart_get_contents();

// Display a message if the cart has more than 5 products.
$item_count = count($items);
if (count($items));
print "<div class='my-cart'><a href='/cart'>Panier d'achat <i class='fa fa-cart-plus'></i> <span class='count'>$item_count</span><span class='count'></span></a></div>";

?>

Answer (score 1):

As for D8 latest version, it looks like uc_cart_get_contents is not working anymore.  So here is how I managed to do it :

```
/** @var \Drupal\uc_cart\CartManager $cartManager */
$cartManager = \Drupal::service('uc_cart.manager');
$items = $cartManager->get()->getContents();
$variables['nbr_cart_items'] = count($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code supplied works "OK" as a quick fix, but it actually counts the **number** of distinct products in the shopping cart, not the number of items.

Here's a snippet that counts the number of **items** using a different Ubercart function than the one employed above:  **uc_cart_get_total_qty()**

```
if (module_exists('uc_cart')) {
  $cart_item_count = uc_cart_get_total_qty();
  print $cart_item_count;
}
```